# How do I setup Zend Debugger in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-framework

I am trying to setup my first PHP Development environment and I am having quite a bit of issues getting the Debug environment to work or more accurately hit breakpoints.

Here is what I have done

1.) Confirmed that php is working in my Apache server on Windows. I did this by creating a test index.php file with phpinfo() in it.

2.) I have installed the Zend Debugger into Eclipse.

3.) I have setup my php.ini file with the following code.

```
[Zend]
zend_extension_ts="c:/php/ext/ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

4.) I have opened up a port for the debugger in the windows firewall, in my case Eclipse says Zend is using 10000.

5.) I have added the dummy.php file into my document root directory.

6.) I have restarted Apache after all of this.

7.) When I go to test my debugger in eclipse I get the following error message.

[image: Zend Error]

8.) When I look in the suggested section. I see this.

[image]

Comment: This does *not* answer your questiom: I normally use the xdebug remote debugger. I can say it works well with Eclipse/PDT (and other IDEs). Also I like the documentation that is a available and I have the feeling more resources and help is available online, too, for it.

Comment: Ok well maybe I will tinker with that some. I haven't even tried it out. In my googling I had a lot of people praising Zend but maybe they went with the whole Server Installation that you can download idk. Does xdebug work for debugging locally too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is misconfiguration of PHP. Check `phpinfo()` if you have Zend Debugger section and validate your configuration.

[image: Zend Debugger entry in phpinfo()]

Note that the `_ts` suffix in `zend_debugger_ts` stands for Thread Safety. If your PHP is 5.3 or greater, or you have Thread Safety disabled (you can check this at phpinfo()), you will have to use `zend_debugger` directive instead of `zend_debugger_ts`.

Also `expose_remotely` acknowledges values `0` (Never), `1` (Always) and `2` (Allowed Hosts); any other value makes Zend Debugger undetectable.

Comment: FINALLY! They are so unclear on the _ts issue. Most tutorials I have followed say if you have installed a thread safe version of PHP then it must have the _ts suffix. Good grief I have been battling this all day....ty.